# civi case API unable to create case

Tags: civicase

Using CiviCRM API v3 Explorer, i can create case without any problem. I can see the new case on case dash board, but using the  php script, there are an error exception happen

> Fatal error: Uncaught CiviCRM_API3_Exception: [unknown error: DB
>   Constraint Violation - case_type_id should possibly be marked as
>   mandatory for Case,create API. If so, please raise a bug report.
>   thrown in
>    /idev/joom/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php
>   on line 45

Here is the snippet code

http://prntscr.com/n17bng

this is the output

http://prntscr.com/n17c6f

Changing code to

http://prntscr.com/n17cky

get this error

http://prntscr.com/n17cqv

Using the explorer code, all is running well

http://prntscr.com/n17d48

Anyone know why this happen ?

Thank you

Comment: In your script are you setting a value for case_type? Can you edit your question to show what parameters you are passing?

Comment: Hi Demerit, i have update  my question, i am passing "house_support", changing using 'case_type_id' => 'housing_support', i have no luck too.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've found a quirk with the explorer where it's smart enough to convert your string to a number, but when run outside the explorer it's expecting a number for case_type_id.

Use case_type_id = 1, which corresponds to housing_support, which you can see by doing a ('CaseType', 'get') call.

Note that if your script is standalone, i.e. not running within an extension or something where you are already logged in, your [bootstrapping](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/bootstrap/) needs to include something that logs you in, e.g. `cv api --user=CMSUser`, where CMSUser is the login name for some user with permission to create cases in your CMS.

Comment: Change to case_type_id = 1, get error "
Fatal error: Uncaught CiviCRM_API3_Exception: [unknown error: DB Error: unknown error thrown in ..."

Comment: How are you "logged in" when running the command? You need to provide a CMS user to use for the creator side of the relationship that gets created.

Comment: I am using php script to create the case. I can create contact, email and address without any problem. Just this case api have strange bugs. The script I have copied from the api explorer.

Comment: Case kind of requires a little more. Is it a standalone script where you are bootstrapping with cv (e.g. https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/bootstrap/)? Then in the cv call you would need to add --user=admin, i.e. a CMS user with appropriate permissions.

Comment: I will try using the cv, need time to learn it 1st, the cv. Thank you for the guide

Comment: I notice you're on joomla. The same link above gives a little bit about bootstraping with joomla, but I don't know joomla very well so don't know how to "log in" during the bootstrap process.

Comment: Yes, i am using joomla.
Using the cv, the error still same, here is the error
http://prntscr.com/n1944f, same error using the joomla.

 _civicrm_api3_case_create_xmlProcessor

on that function, the bugs happen

Comment: Yes it's a relationship error. You have to add --user=something to the cv command. For example if you have a joomla user named Adi who has permission to create cases, you need to say `cv api --user=Adi Case.create ...`

Comment: fantastic... 

it is working 

http://prntscr.com/n196t6

Comment: Great! Can you mark as answered? (click the gray checkmark just to the left of the answer)

Comment: with the cv is working, using the php script, how to assign --user=something

I prefer using the php script than the cv.

Any idea ?

Comment: For joomla I don't know. You'd use something like this: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/bootstrap/#joomla, but you'd have to add some line that logs you in. Maybe you can ask a separate question and someone will answer.

Comment: i will find out..
thank's Demerit